# Newton's binomial problem

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

It is known that in the development of $(x+y)^n$ there is a term of the form $1330x^{n-3}y^3$ and a term of the form $5985x^{n-4}y^4$.
Calculate $n$.

So, I know that the binomial formula of Newton is: $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^kb^{n-k}$, but I can not understand how to establish the relationship and how to solve it.

Someone can help me to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just solve for either $\binom{n}{3}=1330$ or $\binom{n}{4}=5985$. I'd go for the former one since it would end up asking the solution to a **cubic** polynomial equation rather than the latter which ends up in a **quartic** equation. Or even better,

$\dfrac{\binom{n}{4}}{\binom{n}{3}}=\dfrac{5985}{1330}\implies\dfrac{\dfrac{n!}{4!(n-4)!}}{\dfrac{n!}{3!(n-3!)}}=\dfrac{5985}{1330}\implies\dfrac{n-3}{4}=\dfrac{5985}{1330}\implies n=21$

Comment: If you solve both and look at the two equations, you end up with a linear equation - no need for either cubics or quartics.

Comment: Hmmm an edit is about to turn up suggesting just that

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the coefficient of $x^{n-3}y^3$ is 1330, then that must be $\dbinom{n}{3}$; similarly, 5985 must be $\dbinom{n}{4}$. Now write down the definition of $\dbinom{n}{3}$ explicitly. You should be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

The known information tells you that 
$$
{n\choose 3} =1330, {n\choose 4}=5985.
$$